# Authentication Failed (error 530) with Embedded Apache FTP Server

Tags: java, linux, apache, ftp

I am embedding the [apache ftpserver](http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/) in my java web app, I have tried a couple different things and everytime I try to connect to the server via FTP, it says Authentication failed.  I have attached my code, and also the console output when I try to do the logging in.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  I tried running this on OS X and Centos Linux.

```
PropertiesUserManagerFactory userManagerFactory = new PropertiesUserManagerFactory();
userManagerFactory.setFile(new File("/ftpdata/myusers.properties"));
//userManagerFactory.setPasswordEncryptor(new SaltedPasswordEncryptor());
userManagerFactory.setPasswordEncryptor(new ClearTextPasswordEncryptor());
UserManager um = userManagerFactory.createUserManager();
BaseUser user = new BaseUser();
user.setName("andy");
user.setPassword("12345678");
user.setHomeDirectory("/ftpdata/");
um.save(user);

FtpServerFactory serverFactory = new FtpServerFactory();
ListenerFactory factory = new ListenerFactory();
factory.setPort(2225);
serverFactory.addListener("default", factory.createListener());
FtpServer server = serverFactory.createServer();
server.start();








12:03:28,768 INFO  [STDOUT] 12:03:28,768 INFO  [DefaultFtpServer] FTP server started
12:04:14,200 INFO  [STDOUT] 12:04:14,200 INFO  [FtpLoggingFilter] CREATED
12:04:14,208 INFO  [STDOUT] 12:04:14,208 INFO  [FtpLoggingFilter] OPENED
12:04:14,228 INFO  [STDOUT] 12:04:14,228 INFO  [FtpLoggingFilter] RECEIVED: USER andy
12:04:14,230 INFO  [STDOUT] 12:04:14,230 INFO  [FtpLoggingFilter] SENT: 220 Service ready for new user.
12:04:14,232 INFO  [STDOUT] 12:04:14,232 INFO  [FtpLoggingFilter] SENT: 331 User name okay, need password for andy.
12:04:14,233 INFO  [STDOUT] 12:04:14,233 INFO  [FtpLoggingFilter] RECEIVED: PASS *****
12:04:14,236 INFO  [STDOUT] 12:04:14,236 WARN  [PASS] User failed to log in
12:04:14,736 INFO  [STDOUT] 12:04:14,736 WARN  [PASS] Login failure - andy
12:04:14,740 INFO  [STDOUT] 12:04:14,740 INFO  [FtpLoggingFilter] RECEIVED: QUIT
12:04:14,746 INFO  [STDOUT] 12:04:14,746 INFO  [FtpLoggingFilter] SENT: 530 Authentication failed.
12:04:14,746 INFO  [STDOUT] 12:04:14,746 INFO  [FtpLoggingFilter] SENT: 221 Goodbye.
12:04:14,747 INFO  [STDOUT] 12:04:14,746 INFO  [FtpLoggingFilter] CLOSED
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my question may sound stupid but 
i can see in the log

12:04:14,233 INFO  [STDOUT] 12:04:14,233 INFO  [FtpLoggingFilter] RECEIVED: PASS *****

These are 5 stars , your password length is 8 :D

I can see that you pass a property file, is there any chance that you have a password in there?

At last, you create a UserManager, you dont have to pass this object somewhere?

Comment: Yes, you are right.  Thanks for looking over my code.  The solution was to pass the usermanager object to the server factory:
I added this line:

    serverFactory.setUserManager(um);

before  
    FtpServer server = serverFactory.createServer();

Comment: Solved my problem too. The example boilerplate code from the project homepage doesn't add the usermanager to the serverfactory and I pretty much just copypasted the example expecting it to work.